# Get vertical scroll bar position as integer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, scrollbar

I have a RichTextBox and I need to find the position of the vertical scroll bar.

Is there any way to do this without Pinvoke? If not, what is a way to do this WITH Pinvoke?

I need to return an integer value.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way to do this without PInvoke.  You can use PInvoke to call [GetScrollPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetScrollPos.html).

Here's how you can try it.

**Step 1:**  Create a custom RichTextBox control by extending a standard RichTextBox.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

    Public Class MyRichTextBox
        Inherits RichTextBox
        <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
        Public Shared Function GetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
        Private Shared Function SetScrollPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nBar As Integer, ByVal nPos As Integer, ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Integer
        End Function

        Private Const SB_HORZ As Integer = &H0
        Private Const SB_VERT As Integer = &H1

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets and Sets the Horizontal Scroll position of the control.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property HScrollPos() As Integer
            Get
                Return GetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_HORZ)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                SetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_HORZ, value, True)
            End Set
        End Property

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets and Sets the Vertical Scroll position of the control.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property VScrollPos() As Integer
            Get
                Return GetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_VERT)
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                SetScrollPos(DirectCast(Me.Handle, IntPtr), SB_VERT, value, True)
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

This will add two properties to a standard RichTextBox:  HScrollPos and VScrollPos.  These properties will allow you go get and set the horizontal and vertical scrollbar position in your control.

**Step 2:** Create a test form and try out your control.

Create a Winform in the same project as your custom control.  Drop the custom control in the test form and add a button on the form.  In the form's Click event, add the following code to view your custom control's vertical scroll position.

```
Console.WriteLine(myRichTextBox1.VScrollPos)
```

A few things to watch for:

1. If your control is not currently
   displaying a vertical scrollbar, the
   call to HScrollPos will crash your
   program.  There are a few obviously
   ways around this (check that the
   scrollbar is being displayed before
   checking the property, or making the
   vertical scrollbar always visible, etc.).
2. Depending on how the control (and
       possibly form) is sized (not to
       mention changes in the text contents
       of the control), setting the
       VScrollPos can crash your program or
       not restore it to the position it
       was in when the VScrollPos value was
       saved.
3. I've never used this code.  I
       thought your question was
       interesting and did a little bit of
       research to come up with my answer.

Comment: Works great!!! Thanks so much! I wonder why they didn't create a wrapper for that method, it would have made sense lol. I wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: hi :) i tried your code and it works great for getting the value but to set new value to scroll it doesnt it just redraws the scrollbar of that control :( could you help? here is what i do: http://pastesite.com/22927 thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah, Jay's solution does what promised: it changes the positions of scrollbars. What it doesn't change is the position of the CONTENT of the richtextbox.

Here is the solution I found over at codeproject.com: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/293542/VB-Net-Custome-RichTextBox-SetScrollPos

```
Public Class Rtbscrollfix
    Inherits RichTextBox

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As System.Drawing.Point) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Const WM_USER = &H400
    Private Const EM_GETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 221
    Private Const EM_SETSCROLLPOS = WM_USER + 222

    Public Property ScrollY() As Integer
        Get
            Dim pt As New System.Drawing.Point
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, EM_GETSCROLLPOS, 0, pt)
            Return pt.Y
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, EM_SETSCROLLPOS, 0, New System.Drawing.Point(0, value))
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```